# in Flex, what is the best way to detect if the os came back from standby/hibernate/sleep?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to be able to tell when the os has came back from sleep/hibernate/standby.

Problem I'm having is that I have a timer that needs to fire at certain time. The delay is calculated so that it will fire on certain hour:min:sec. Problem is when the os goes to sleep, the timer is "paused," which caused the timer to fire on wrong time. I would like to be able to update the timer delay when the os comes back from sleep but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do in Flex is use a faster timer and keep track of the last time the timer fired.  so instead of setting a timer to fire a few hours from now, set it to fire a minute from now and keep firing and checking current time vs due time until it's time to trigger the real event.

If all the timer is doing during these interim times is checking current time against due time, it won't have a measurable effect on performance.

Comment: yeah.. that's probably what I will end up doing... I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: @lordofthefobs, There's a checkmark image underneath the vote tally for each answer.  You can click on this to mark an answer as correct.  You haven't accepted any answers for any of your questions even though you've indicated in comments or your own answers that you went with something posted.  You should go back to your questions and click the checkmark where appropriate, accepting the correct answer.